# How to call <iframe> attribute

Tags: jquery

i have a div in which i have stored an iframe like this:

```
<div  id="vplyer1" class="frame">
<iframe src="" width="480" frameborder="no" height="270"></iframe>
</div>

and my jquery is
function playme(vurls, menu_el,vplyer ){

    $('#vplyer1>iframe').attr('src','');
//$('div.frame>iframe').attr('src',''); 
//var src = $('iframe',this).attr('src');
    document.getElementById(vplyer).src=vurls;

    for(var i=1; i<15; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            var dd="hv"+i
        collapse_el = document.getElementById( dd );
        collapse_el.style.display = 'none';
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            console.log("catch ");

        }

    }

    collapse_el1= document.getElementById(menu_el);
    collapse_el1.style.display = 'block';
 }
```

i am not able to get the value of SRC attribute using my div id.
Please suggest the solution

Comment: Where are you calling `playme ` function?

Comment: Where are these:`#menu_el`, `#dd`, `#collapse_el1` and what are these: `vurls`, `menu_el`,`vplyer`? *"i am not able to get the value of SRC attribute using my div id. "*  Divs cannot have a `src` attribute and the singular word "i" is always capitalized in English.